# babel.config.js vs .babelrc (Vue + Express in same directory)

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, babel-preset-env, babel-cli

You can directly skip to the last part of this section for the **exact questions**? For full context, read from the start.

This is how I initiated my Vue project:

```
vue create awesome-frontend
```

choose all defaults and ended up with `babel.config.js` file in the root directory with these contents:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

Next up, I installed `@babel/cli`, `@babel/preset-env` and `express` using `npm` and created a demo `server.js` in the root directory with following contents:

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const port = 8080;

app.get('/',(req,res)=> {
  res.send('Express Home page')
});

app.listen(port,() => console.log(`Server started running on ${port}`));
```

Now I wish to compile `server.js` using babel with preset: `preset-env` and I tried the followings things:

1) Created a `.babelrc` in the root directory with following contents:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ]
}
```

2) Tried setting preset in the command line `npx babel --preset @babel/preset-env server.js -d dist`

In both cases, `babel.config.js` seems to take priority. If that actually is the case, then how can I tell babel to ignore this file in some scenarios. Is there a way out?

One solution to my problem was to copy the contents of `babel.config.js` to `.babelrc` and then delete `babel.config.js` so that my VUE build are not affected (I don't really know what happens under the hood) and then I could build `server.js` by ignoring `.babelrc` using this command

```
npx babel --no-babelrc --presets=@babel/preset-env server.js -d dist
```

Now I wish to know what exactly is happening here and is there any better solution to my problem?

Q1: Is there any way to ignore `babel.config.js` using command line just like we can ignore `.babelrc` with `--no-babelrc` ?

Q2: Is there any way to use multiple babel config files under the same project? So that while compiling with babel, we can mention which config file to use?

Q3: Are `babel.config.js` and `.babelrc` essentially the same? As I mentioned above, I copied the contents of `babel.config.js` to `.babelrc` and then deleted `babel.config.js`. But all VUE builds are working fine. Is that future safe?

Tried googling, but could find anything useful.
Thanks, in advance.